# Adsense - We found that your site is down or unavailable

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

It's my first time to try adsense in a site I made from scratch

I tried to add adsense to my website over 10 times and everytime it says:
We found that your site is down or unavailable:

[image]

And the code provided is already in the `<head></head>` section of the website

```
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-2733350805802981",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
```

website : https://www.a3traf.com